# Writing HTML with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am new to jQuery. I want to write the following HTML (along with the classes) using jQuery. How can I do this?

```
<div class="phnbr">
  <div class="phtext">hi how are you, <a target="_blank" href="http://www.xyz.com">click here.</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this in jQuery?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$('<div class="phnbr"> \
  <div class="phtext">hi how are you, <a target="_blank" href="http://www.xyz.com">click here.</a> \
  </div> \
</div>'); // bang done!
```

Comment: Not the best way to represent jQuery imho ;)

Comment: @NKCSS, This one would be faster that your solution. Moreover, no need of long chained statements. Moreover, shows the power of JQuery to a beginner. etc etc

Comment: I like this answer as it is quite readable how the HTML structure is. Creating objects for each tag and using `append` and `appendTo` is already confusing with 5+ tags in my opinion.

Answer (score 16):

```
$('<div>').addClass('phnbr').append($('<div>').addClass('phtext').append('hi how are you, ').append($('<a>').attr({ target: '_blank', href: 'http://www.xyc.com'}).text('click here.')));
```

Answer (score 5):

Well you can just use [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) or the other [DOM Insertion Functions](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/)

```
$(document.body).append('<div class="phnbr"><div class="phtext">hi how are you, <a target="_blank" href="http://www.xyz.com">click here.</a></div></div>');
```