# Trying to get data from json through javascript and display on jquery mobile page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, json

I want get the data coming in JSON through a php url using JAVASCRIPT and displaying that data in JQuery mobile "li" tag(it'll be a complete category list) but using the code given below isn't displaying anthing. I'll be very thankful, I am stuck in this thing from last 8 hours.

```
<script>
                  var session_id = localStorage.getItem('session_id');
                  var user_id = localStorage.getItem('user_id');  
            $(document).ready(function() {
             //$('#output').html('somestuff');

                $('#loginForm').submit(function() {
                    //$('#output').html('Connecting....');
                    var postTo = 'http://localhost/categories.php';
                    //alert(postTo);
                    $.post(postTo,{userid: $('[name=user_id]').val() ,   sessionid:  $('[name=session_id]').val()} , 
                        function(data) {

                            if(data.status == 'true') {

                                $("#userdata tbody").html("");
                                $.getJSON(postTo,function(data){
                                $.each(data.members, function(i,user){
                                var tblRow =
                                "<li data-theme="e">"
                                 +"<a data-transition="flow" href="">"+user.category+"</a>"
                                  +"</li>";
                                $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
                                });
                                });


                            } else {

                                window.open("./MyApp.html","_self");
                            }

                        },'json');

                    return false;
                });
            });
            </script>
```

Comment: put a debugger after `function(data) {` and check what it returns in `data` as well as check your console if der is anything wrong

Comment: Can I see your complete code ? (e.g html and categories.php)

Answer (score 0):

this   `$(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");` should be

something like

```
$("#userdata tbody").appendTo(tblRow);
```

Read more [here about appending content  to element](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

and

```
 var tblRow ="<li data-theme="e">"  
                             +"<a data-transition="flow" href="">"+user.category+"</a>"
                             +"</li>";
```

change it into

```
 var tblRow ='<li data-theme="e">' 
                             +'<a data-transition="flow" href="">'+user.category+'</a>'
                             +'</li>';
```

Check your console what it says to precise on your errors and where exactly it fails.

Refer this question for [writing html with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593012/writing-html-with-jquery)

Comment: Check your console for errors and tell us exactly where it fails?

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error at `+"<a data-transition="flow" href="">"+`. "flow" is outside quotes (so it's counted as a var, but you didn't used "+") so you should only put single quotes before and after "flow".
Same goes for the href.